# Change keyboard layout in gdm

Tags: login, keyboard-layout, login-screen

I just installed ubuntu-14.04, and during installation I chose two keyboard layouts: En-us and Ru-ru, and created user with en-us login/password. It successfully installed. When it loads the login window there is only one Ru-ru keyboard layout, there is no En-us and I can't login with my en-us login/passsword. How can I fix this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you installed two keyboard layouts, you should see a white square in the top right corner of your login screen showing the one that is active right now. In this case, it would say Ru. If you click on that you may be able to choose the English keyboard layout.

I hope that helps.